# How do I use PL/SQL to_date with a variable in Groovy?

Tags: sql, oracle, groovy, plsql, ora-17004

I've got the following small Groovy script that just does a count of rows in the database for a specific date.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def today= new GregorianCalendar()
def dateString = "${today.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1}/${today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-1}/${today.get(Calendar.YEAR)}"

def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:bc/bc@nemesis:1521:billctr", "bc","bc", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")

def sqlLine = "select count(id) as count from bc_payment where trunc(paymentdate) = to_date(${dateString}, \'MM/DD/YYYY\')"
println(sqlLine)
def payCount = sql.execute(sqlLine)
println payCount
```

to_date requires single-quotes around the date you pass in. If I leave them off, I get `SQLException: Invalid column type` but if I put \' around the variable, I get a warning from Groovy

```
WARNING: In Groovy SQL please do not use quotes around dynamic expressions (which start with $) as this means we cannot use a JDBC PreparedStatement and so is a security hole. Groovy has worked around your mistake but the security hole is still there. The expression so far is: select count(id) as count from bc_payment where trunc(paymentdate) = to_date('?', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Is there a better way of doing this without to_date or formatting the variable differently? I'm new to Groovy so any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (I hope I haven't introduced a syntax error, no Groovy here...)

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def today= new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime())

def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:bc/bc@nemesis:1521:billctr", "bc","bc", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")

def sqlLine = "select count(id) as count from bc_payment where trunc(paymentdate) = ?"
println(sqlLine)
def payCount = sql.execute(sqlLine, [today])
println payCount
```

Edit: replaced

```
def today = new Date()
```

with

```
def today= new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime())
```

Comment: I think you need a java.sql.Date instance in order to compare it to a Date column without a timestamp.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, I think I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer by a developer with similar problems.

I found that the problem was could be fixed by changing the declaration:

```
def sqlLine = "... ${yourString} ..."
```

... which creates sqlLine as a GStringImpl-object. If instead you declare sqlLine like this:

```
String sqlLine = "... ${yourString} ..."
```

... we resolve the variables inline and receive a String-object. This way groovy.sql.Sql never know that we created the sql dynamically.

Comment: You haven't fixed the security risk, you just tricked Groovy into not being able to spot it and so it doesn't show the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can read the sql instance parameters from the DataSource doing the followng:

```
def _url      = ConfigurationHolder.config.dataSource.url
def _username = ConfigurationHolder.config.dataSource.username
def _password = ConfigurationHolder.config.dataSource.password
def _driver   = ConfigurationHolder.config.dataSource.driverClassName

def sql = Sql.newInstance(_url, _username, _password, _driver)

// For the paging
def int max    = Math.min(params.max ? params.max.toInteger() : 25,  100)
def int offset = params.offset.toInteger()
def int last   = offset + max

def month= params.month_value
```

I use Oracle **TO_DATE** and **TO_TIMESTAMP** function. In my case it is as follows:

```
query = "select * from " +
          "(SELECT  reporting.id, " +
          "company_id as comp, " +      
          "to_date(TO_CHAR(invoice,'dd.mm.YYYY')) as invoice, " +
          "TO_CHAR(last_updated,'dd.mm.YYYY HH:MI') as erstelltAm, " +
          "row_number() over (" + sortByStr + ") as row_num FROM reporting, company " +
          "WHERE reporting.company_id = company.id) " +
              "reporting.month = TO_TIMESTAMP(" + month + ", 'dd.mm.yy')""
        "where ROW_NUM between " + offset + " and " + last;
```